# Sait-on jamais? au passé

Tags: expressions, temps-grammatical

J'ai vu plusieurs renseignements sur cette expression, mais j'ai une autre question : peut-on la mettre au passé ou bien doit-on la laisser au présent ?

Par exemple :

> Il préféra vérifier, sait-on jamais ?

ou bien :

> Il préféra vérifier, savait-on jamais ?

Answer (score 3):

L'expression est figée. On la rencontre cependant parfois au passé, mais c'est très rare :

> *Elle songea à écrire au notaire, puis elle se dit que ce serait imprudent, peut-être ; **savait-on jamais**, avec les hommes de loi !* André Cayatte, *Le traquenard*, 1939.

On peut aussi trouver quelques exemples au futur :

> *Pourquoi m'étais-je attaché à ce cadran public plutôt qu'à tout autre ? **Saura-t-on jamais** ?* Alphonse Allais, *On n'est pas des bœufs*, 1896

Comment: Merci, c'est ce que je pensais, mais je n'étais vraiment pas sûre!